# Generating simple plot from csv using Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to make a graph of the first column ('Time') of a csv file plotted against the the second column ('Bid').

Here's what I have so far.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
headers = ['Time','Bid','Ask']

df = pd.read_csv('quotes_format.csv')

x = df['Time']
y = df['Bid']

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

[The csv file looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDTTf.png)

This fails and returns exit code 1. How would I fix this so it would generate the graph I'm looking for?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify what the names of each column in the dataframe are with the parameter `names`.

`headers = ['Time','Bid','Ask']
df = pd.read_csv('quotes_format.csv', names=headers)`

Here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for the pandas read_csv function.